# Unable to append records via Spark

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I have a SQL Server table with a primary key column.

I want to perform an append operation. But before that, it checks if the given record exists in the SQL Server or not. If it exists, then it will delete the record from SQL Server and append the new record.

I tried to delete the given record from SQL Server, commit the transaction, and then append the new record.

But it is throwing error.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
lock.acquire()

cursor.execute(f"delete from {tablename} where category_id in {category_id_in_string}")
cursor.execute(sql_query)

sql_query = f"select * from {tablename}"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
for r in records:
    print(r)

sql_connection.commit()

lock.release()

categories_new_df \
    .write \
    .mode("append") \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .options(**sql_server_properties) \
    .save()
print(f"New records are appended with category_id in {category_id_in_string}")

sql_connection.commit()
```

Error message: -

> 23/12/08 10:26:17 WARN TOKEN: ConnectionID:8 ClientConnectionId: 3cdf4141-1034-48b2-8021-ca3a3b149e39: SQLServerConnection.supportsTransactions: Discarding unexpected TDS_COLMETADATA (0x81)
> 23/12/08 10:26:17 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 39.0 (TID 277)
> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: **Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_category_id'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'retail.categories'. The duplicate key value is (6).**

I tried a numerous number of ways. But they are not working. Kindly, let me know how can I achieve the append operation using Spark into SQL Server table (JDBC format) after deleting the record using PyMssql.

Comment: Maybe categories_new_df contains duplicates. Hard to say because you have anonymized the code beyond recognition

Comment: No @siggemannen. categories_new_df doesn't contain any duplicate. It only has 1 row that needs to be appended. First, category_id for the same record will be deleted from sql_server then the entire record is getting appended. I am not appending any duplicate records.